# If a magnetizable object is subjected to a large magnetic field, do its dimensions or volume change?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'd like any clues as to whether subjecting something to an intense magnetic field changes its shape or density in any way.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/449136/classical-explanation-for-volume-conservation-in-magnetorestriction

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The effect occurs in ferrous material when subjected to a powerful magnetic field and is known as *magnetostriction*. The effect can be easily detected in electrical transformers handling 60 Hz AC because the rapid (but very slight) shape changes which it causes within the transformer core cause the core to emit a faint humming sound.

Answer (score 1):

For small fields, there is normally constriction parallel to the field and expansion perpendicular to the field, with no change in volume. This can be explained either in terms of shifting of domain walls or in terms of the tension carried by magnetic field lines parallel to themselves and the pressure in the transverse direction, as described by the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor. The lack of a volume change was originally observed by Joule, who discovered the penomenon in 1842. There are also cases where the volume can change ([Chopra and Wuttig, Nature 521, 340–343 (2015)](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature19064.pdf?origin=ppub)).